# Two classes in a larger class share data

Tags: c++, class, inheritance

I have a class that contains objects of two other classes.  I need one of the classes to be able to get data from the other one. Here's an example.

```
class Nom{ /*says what we're eating*/ };
class Chew{ /*stuff that needs to know about what we are eating from nom*/ };

class BigBurrito 
{
   Nom n;
   Chew c;
};
```

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: * finally realizes the value of pointers* :O

Comment: thanks everyone, does this have a certain name so that I can learn about it. I'm not too experienced so I'd like to check it out a bit more in depth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about passing a pointer to the instance of `Nom` into `Chew`? Along these lines:

```
class Nom {};

class Chew
{
private:
    Nom *m_nom;
public:
    Chew(Nom *nom)
    : m_nom(nom)
    {}
};

class BigBurrito
{
private:
    Nom m_nom;
    Chew m_chew;
public:
    BigBurrito()
    : m_chew(&m_nom)
    {}
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You can either make a pointer to the other class a member of the class

```
class Nom{
   Chew* chew;
};
class Chew{ /*stuff that needs to know about what we are eating from nom*/ };

class BigBurrito 
{
   Nom n;  //contains pointer to c
   Chew c;
};
```

or pass it via a parameter to the function that performs the operation.

```
class Nom
{
   void performOperationOnChew(Chew& c);
};
class Chew{ /*stuff that needs to know about what we are eating from nom*/ };

class BigBurrito 
{
   Nom n;
   Chew c;
   void doTheOperation()
   {
      n.performOperationOnChew(c);
   }
};
```

The second option is cleaner OOP, since `Chew` doesn't logically belong to `Nom`.

Comment: +1 The whole design in the question seems a little suspect though - if `Chew` is an action, as I guess in retrospect its name suggests (I find it interesting that my reflex reaction to this without thinking about design issues is pass in a pointer...hmm), then why is it contained in `BigBurrito` like that? Seems a bit odd.

Comment: @StuartGolodetz I actually tried to abstract the names out. I just looked at it as class A, B and C, with composition. :)

Comment: @StuarGolodetz yeah I just came up with the names as a representation.  I didn't really think about them very hard.

Answer (score 0):

Just pass in a reference to `n` (`Nom`) to your `Chew` constructor.

Comment: Well, technically, just adding a parameter to the constructor won't do anything...

Comment: Well the idea was he would do something with it. :)